# How can I set value form a specific xml String node?

Tags: javascript, xml, string, set

I already read the string and build an html table from it:

```
var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</BrandName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</BrandName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe></All>";

$(document).ready(function() {  
xmlDoc=$.parseXML( ShoesXML );
$(xmlDoc).find("Shoe").each(function(i, n) {
    var html = "<tr>\n" + 
        "<td><span>" + $(n).find("Name").text() + "</span></td>\n" +
        "<td>" +  $(n).find("BrandName").text() + "</td>\n" +
        "<td>" + $(n).find("ReleaseDate").text() + "</td>\n" + 
        "<td><img src='" + $(n).find("Picture").text() + "'></td>\n" +
        "</tr>";
    $("table.shoetable tbody").append(html);
});
});
```

I tried to set a value this way but no success:

```
$(n).find("Name").text("NEW VALUE")
```

Comment: Where do you call `$(n).find("Name").text("NEW VALUE")`?

Comment: `var html = "<tr>\n" + 
        "<td><span>" + $(n).find("Name").text("NEW VALUE") + "</span></td>\n" +
        "<td>" +  $(n).find("BrandName").text() + "</td>\n" +
        "<td>" + $(n).find("ReleaseDate").text() + "</td>\n" + 
        "<td><img src='" + $(n).find("Picture").text() + "'></td>\n" +
        "</tr>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `.textContext` before building `HTML` string

```
    $(n).find("Name").text("NEW VALUE")

    var html = "<tr>\n" + 
    "<td><span>" + $(n).find("Name").text() + "</span></td>\n" +
    "<td>" +  $(n).find("BrandName").text() + "</td>\n" +
    "<td>" + $(n).find("ReleaseDate").text() + "</td>\n" + 
    "<td><img src='" + $(n).find("Picture").text() + "'></td>\n" +
    "</tr>";
```